# Настройка Nginx на использование нескольких директорий

Tags: html, ubuntu, nginx, config

Есть конфиг nginx который при обращении к http://example.com/sellers должен отдавать сервер с папки /data/sellers В другом случае - из папки /data/customers

Nginx конфигурация:

```
    server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
index index.html index.htm home.html;

location /sellers {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    rewrite ^/sellers/?(.*) /$1 break;
    root   /data/sellers;
}

location / {
    root   /data/customers;
}
}
```

Все работает, однако не совсем корректно: при обращении к sellers сервер почему-то использует index.html с папки /data/customers/index.html А все остальное из папки /data/sellers (то есть правильно) При обращении не к /sellers все работает корректно. В чем может быть дело? Почему nginx берет не правильный index.html файл, хотя все остальное грузит верно?

Изменено: вот полный конфиг (поменял немного но ошибка при обращении к /sellers):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    index index.html index.htm home.html;

    location /auth {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://192.168.1.229:6999;
    }

    location /hooks {
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://192.168.1.229:9000;
    }

    location /sellers {
        root    /data/sellers;
    }

    location / {
        root   /data/customers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всегда смотрите error.log. Я уверен, что там написано про ненайденный файл `/data/sellers/sellers/что-вы-там-хотели.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строчка - `rewrite ^/sellers/?(.*) /$1 break;` убирает sellers из URL. Неудивительно, что у вас index.html из другой папки возвращается. Удивительно другое - что больше багов вы не нашли :)

Зачем вообще `rewrite`? Откуда у вас `proxy_set_header` и что они делают в отсутствии `proxy_pass`?

Вот правильная конфигурация:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  index index.html index.htm home.html;
  root /data/customers;

  location /sellers {
    alias /data/sellers;
  }
}
```

Чувствуете, насколько все было просто? :)

Comment: Сейчас буду проверять работу. Я не до конца объяснил наверно: кроме этих двух папок есть другие. Например: при обращении к hooks надо сделать редирект на nodejs сервер
при обращении на /auth надо тоже сделать переадресацию в другое место и тд
Сейчас отпишусь
Спасибо за ответ в любом случае!

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, добавил в конце полный конфиг файл. Сейчас при обращении к корню все работает, а при обращении к /sellers - выдает ошибку 404 Not Found

Если вместо root    /data/sellers; прописать alias /data/sellers; - файл берется нужный, однако директория остается /data/customers почему-то

Comment: @DenisAdamenko ответ от этого не меняется, секции `auth` и `hooks` вы можете оставить как есть. По поводу ошибки Not Found - проверьте путь к физической папке sellers, в первом варианте своего ответа я там допустил опечатку (сейчас исправлена).

Comment: Почти все работает. Однако в index.html есть подключение скрипта:
<script src="/node_modules/ng2-pagination/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js"></script>

и выдает ошибку что скрипт не найден. Он есть в папке /data/sellers, однако его нет в /data/customers
То есть он его не там ожидает?

Comment: Запрос за скриптом придёт на адрес `/node_modules/...`, как видим этот адрес не начинается с `/sellers/`, поэтому скрипт будет искаться в дефолтной папке.

Comment: Почему-то сервер думает что <script src="/node_modules/ng2-pagination/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js"></script>

надо ожидать здесь: /node_modules/ng2-pagination/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js

а должно быть:
/sellers/node_modules/ng2-pagination/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js

?

Comment: @DenisAdamenko подключайте скрипт из правильной папки!

Comment: @DenisAdamenko сервер так думает исключительно потому что так и должно быть.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо огромное!!!! Очень вам благодарен за помощь

Comment: Тут вместо `alias /data/sellers;` можно использовать `root /data`, это немного быстрее в плане производительности. http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias в конце описания директивы alias

Comment: Вижу, "Если location и последняя часть значения директивы совпадают то используйте root"

Comment: @AlexeyTen если вдруг понадобится сделать третий сайт или перенести существующий - то вариант с `root /data` может показаться слишком магическим для неподготовленного человека :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov да судя по вопросам, конфигурация nginx кажется людям магической в любом случае…

Comment: Есть такое, зато работает :)
Кстати я не стал прописывать путь /sellers/node_modules/...
Я просто убрал первый слеш и сервер сам выбирает правильную папку
То есть сейчас просто: node_modules/...

Comment: @DenisAdamenko это было правильное решение!

Comment: @DenisAdamenko только уточнение: папку "сам выбирает" не сервер, а браузер. Серверу всегда приходит полный путь.

Comment: Согласен с вами :)